# Подсчет количества единичных бит

Tags: c++

Нужно посчитать количество единичных бит, запрещается использовать любые арифметические операции (даже инкремент) и любые сторонние библиотеки (кроме iostream). Разрешается использование циклов и условных операторов.

Входные данные: 7
Выходные данные: 3

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main(){ 
    int t,x = 0; 
    cin >> x; 
    while (x != 0) { 
        t += 1; x &= x-1; 
    } 
    cout<<t; 
}
```

Пытался делать, но получается только с инкрементом

Comment: Что  именно не получается? Приведите пример кода, над которым работали.

Comment: Битовые операции разрешены?

Comment: Да, разрешены. Этот кусок кода работает, но там использованы ариф. операции "t+=1" и "x &= x-1"

Comment: Хм... полюбому в программе будет счётчик, и его придётся инкрементировать, а это арифметическая операция... Странная задача :) Это вообще реально?

Comment: Препод сказал, есть 2 варианта, либо сделать какую-то метку в массиве и передвигать её, либо прибавлять единицу битовой операцией

Comment: обожаю наше образование бессмысленное и беспощадное

Comment: @zcorvid счётчик не обязателен. Цикл... можно с циклом, можно 8 или 32 ифа налепить. Можно длинное-тернарное. Как фантазия позволяет.

Comment: Кусок кода - публиковать в вопрос. Будет тема для обсуждения. Два несвязаных куска кода которые в коментариях - ниочём не говорят.

Comment: @nick_n_a,это будет эпично) Можно ещё нормальный такой switch шлёпнуть с перебором всевозможных вариантов :)

Comment: Не обязательно ведущий i делать. Можно сделать ведущим сам аргумент;) Но и ведущий i тоже хороший вариант. Вариантов реализации можно придумать много. Аналог свичу - массив с ответами;) `return answ[arg];`

Comment: Унарный минус относится к арифметическим операциям?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот же задание..

```
unsigned increment(unsigned value) {
    unsigned bit = 1;
    while (value & bit) {
        value ^= bit;
        bit <<= 1;
    }
    value |= bit;
    return value;
}

int ones(unsigned i) {
    unsigned bit = 1;
    int res = 0;
    while (bit) {
        if (i & bit) 
            res = increment(res);
        bit <<= 1;  
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: `for (unsigned bit = 1; !((value ^= bit) & bit); bit <<= 1);`